# Can't find a way to make my usb pen Realtek 8811CU work on kali linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, drivers, git

I've been trying the whole afternoon to make it work . I followed many guides but nothing seems to work . I'm kinda new to kali linux. I'm using it on virtualbox and first thing i've done was to set up the usb filter from the settings of the virtual machine . Next thing i've tried was downloading the drivers for the chipset of my usb pen which is the one in the title.

I think i get some problems in this phase. These are the commands i used .

```
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
cd rtl8821CU
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
sudo modprobe 8821cu
```

I also tried installing drivers of the same chipset from others github's projects but nothing.

Comment: @John: That's...not a good answer. Zero effort, zero troubleshooting, just "give up and buy a different adapter". If it wasn't deleted, I would've downvoted it too. (Especially for "Realtek is not on the list" when *half the items* in the list are Realtek chipsets.)

Comment: @John Are you aware Realtek is the chipset inside, NOT the brand name, aren't you? You should be if you're using Kali.

Comment: @John https://kennyvn.com/best-wireless-adapters-kali-linux/ **#5 ALFA AWUS036ACH is Realtek RTL8812AU** . Also https://www.kali.org/docs/nethunter/wireless-cards/ where Realtek is mentioned 11 times!

Comment: @John You're completely and hopelessly wrong and that's why you shouldn't be answering this kind of questions. **Realtek RTL8811CU IS THE CHIPSET!** Brand, if any, is totally irrelevant. It requires the same exact drivers in any OS, period.

Comment: @John FYI: Most often recommend Pandas for Kali (PAU05, PAU6 and PAU09) are indeed supported since a long time ago because they're based on very old Ralink chipsets. There are many others that do work even in monitor mode, the ONLY reason there's a special list for Kali/Parrot. Otherwise, if monitor mode isn't required, anything that works out-of-the-box in Debian AUTOMATICALLY works in Kali, end of story. You have been told this exact same fact too many times already.

Comment: @John Wrong again. It may need additional drivers and we don't know what happened when the OP tried to install. The OP is among the people who SHOULDN'T be using Kali, the same as you. The OP even tagged this as "Ubuntu", this shows how much they actually know what they're doing, i.e., not much if anything at all.

Comment: @per-i-giochi Let's get something straight first: KALI is NOT for beginners: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ , has one specific task and nothing else, NOT a regular Linux distro, NOT apt for daily usage as desktop Linux, etc. Questions such as yours are then, understandably quite frowned upon: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me (John needs to understand this too, apparently). You may want to [edit] the question and describe what happened with the "commands".

Comment: 1) Does the USB adapter show up in `lsusb` within the VM? 2) Does the 8821cu module show up in `lsmod`? 3) What does `dmesg` show after connecting the adapter and loading the module?